# Is there any way to group the close numbers of a list by numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I've a list

`x = [1,3,2,89,26,31,35,78,5,3,70]`

What I want is something like below:

```
[[1,2,3,5], [26,31,35], [70,78,89]]
```

Is it possible to group the close integer elements out of a integer list in python?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify what exactly "close" should mean in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize your question is specifically about numpy, but as Ben pointed out, it would be up to you to decide the threshold, which may not be easy to do.

This sounds to me like a basic kmeans exercise where you set the number of groups and let the model do the rest.  In this example I've chosen 3 clusters to match your output, but ideally you might use something like the [elbow method](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html) to pick the optimum number of clusters so that your separation between groups is the best possible.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

x = [1,3,2,89,26,31,35,78,5,3,70]
x = sorted(x)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(np.reshape(x,(-1,1)))

[[i[0] for i in list(d)] for g,d in groupby(list(zip(x,kmeans.labels_)), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 3, 5], [26, 31, 35], [70, 78, 89]]
```

Edit:

If you'd like a function:

```
def make_groups(data, n_groups):
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import groupby
    data = sorted(data)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_groups, random_state=0).fit(np.reshape(data,(-1,1)))

    return [[i[0] for i in list(d)] for g,d in groupby(list(zip(data,kmeans.labels_)), key=lambda x: x[1])]


x = [1,3,2,89,26,31,35,78,5,3,70]

make_groups(x, 3)
```

Comment: for some list of integers it throws the exception 
`TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key' `
example list:
`[450,330,440,570,570,440,650,6000,2600,3200]`

Comment: Runs fine on my end `[[330, 440, 440, 450, 570, 570, 650], [2600, 3200], [6000]]`    Make sure you are copy/pasting the code exactly and just replacing the list of numbers

Answer (score 2):

For a prespecified threshold `thr`, let's say that a group of integers is "close" if each integer is less than `thr` away from the next largest of the group. Under this definition, we can group the close numbers together with the following function.

```
import numpy as np

def group(a,thr):
    x = np.sort(a)
    diff = x[1:]-x[:-1]
    gps = np.concatenate([[0],np.cumsum(diff>=thr)])
    return [x[gps==i] for i in range(gps[-1]+1)]
```

For example, `group([1,3,2,89,26,31,35,78,5,3,70],20)` returns

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 3, 5]), array([26, 31, 35]), array([70, 78, 89])]
```